# How to get Ubuntu in iso format

Tags: system-installation, iso

I downloaded Ubuntu desktop iso file. I want to install it in my VirtualBox. After downloading it, the file was in .zip format and I used my WinRAR software to unzip it. After the unzipping process, the original file was not in iso format. How do I get the .zip download Ubuntu desktop to be in iso format?My challenges is that the Oracle virtual Box does not recognized the Ubuntu desktop Iso file I downloaded.What I suspected is that after the Extract of the file from Zip format.The file that was extracted was not in ISO format.So how do i get the file to be in Iso format?

Comment: What is "Ubuntu desktop ios". Where did you download the file from?

Comment: You meant ISO format?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant the Ubuntu ISO installation file - here are the download locations :

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/

Ubuntu 15.04 -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/vivid/